# how well to align your labels and inputs in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am learning boostrap, I know CSS enough.

In Bootstrap 4, I would like to create 2 inputs and 2 labels like this example below in HTML / CSS.

[image]

*html*

```
<div class="about">
   <div class="section-about">
      <label>Nom du Titulaire</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
   </div>
   <div class="section-about">
      <label>Intitulé</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
   </div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #e6ebb1;
  font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.about {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.about .section-about {
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.about .section-about label {
  margin: 5px 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
}
.about .section-about input {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I have tried to adapt in Bootstrap below. But, I think that the code isn't complete and correct...

[image]

Sorry, I don't find what I want to do on google.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link
         href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         />
   </head>
   <body>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="container">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-auto col-form-label">
               <label for="dishes-0-dish">Nom du Titulaire</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
               <input
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width: 50%"
                  id="dishes-0-dish"
                  name="dishes-0-dish"
                  type="text"
                  />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-auto col-form-label">
               <label for="dishes-0-dish">Numéro de portefeuille</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
               <input
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width: 50%"
                  id="dishes-0-dish"
                  name="dishes-0-dish"
                  type="text"
                  />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare column by it's size for your desire design. Because auto adopt the space after immediately done the first one. So, if your both text size is not same it will not show like as you want. On the other hand you can declare width for the label which is similar like declare column.

Follow the below code modification.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML CSS JS</title>
      <link
         href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         rel="stylesheet"
         />
   </head>
   <body>
      <br /> <br />
      <div class="container">
         <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
               <label for="dishes-0-dish">Nom du Titulaire</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <input
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width: 50%"
                  id="dishes-0-dish"
                  name="dishes-0-dish"
                  type="text"
                  />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-right">
               <label for="dishes-0-dish">Numéro de portefeuille</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <input
                  class="form-control"
                  style="width: 50%"
                  id="dishes-0-dish"
                  name="dishes-0-dish"
                  type="text"
                  />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Rechercher</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thank you very much.